# Can large international mail be sent from any post office in Tokyo?

Tags: tokyo, mail

I will be traveling to Tokyo this month for the World Kendo Championship. After the competition I intend to continue traveling through Japan, and I would rather not bring the Kendo equipment with me as I have no further plans to practice. The easiest solution would be sending it home.

That means sending a large package (~20 kg) internationally from Tokyo (through surface mail).

Can I do this at any post office or is this service only offered at specific locations?

Specifically, I am interested in [this post office](http://map.japanpost.jp/pc/syousai.php?id=300100467000). I wasn't able to find anything on the page about international mail or packages (though I used Google Translate, so it might be there anyway).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mail.

Comment: The question is obviously relevant to travelers who are looking to offload some weight during the trip (as I am, and it's a very common situation), and while it is not about anything sepecifically in the white list of subjects in the help center, it is not in the black list either. To sum it up - it addresses a problem related to travel, and it's not a bad question.

Comment: Welcome to T.SE, please edit your question to include the relevant details, community then can vote to re-open if they think it is about travel after the edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can normally send any type of mail, including international, from any post office in Japan (and yours is no exception, otherwise it would be mentioned on the page). They can also come to your place to collect the parcel at no charge if you prefer (I suspect that the reason you want to send it from this particular office is that the parcel is to heavy to carry to others), just inquire at a bigger post office where they have English-speaking staff.

Comment: Depending on how you intend to travel, there is also the option to store the equipment at both Tokyo airports.  The cost at Haneda would be 800yen/day (http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/premises/service/delivery.html) which might even end up being less than the postage fee you'd incur.

Comment: Yes, that obviously depends on the use case. If you just store it in a locker, you have to bring it as checked luggage, and it might exceed your allowance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I will be traveling for about a month after the competition, so the cost of leaving it at the airport is too high.